# React : best way to Import / Export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a project in `React` and I'm not sure if the approach to import/export is right.

I'm exporting my components with an `index.js` file inside my Components folder like this:

```
export {default as Card} from './Card/Card'
export {default as CardList} from './CardList/CardList'
```

Each component is a const and I'm exporting it as:
`export default Card` and `export default CardList`

I'm using `export default` two times

1. in the `index.js`
2. in each component file

Is this the best practice to use an index file to export the components?

Thanks!

Comment: I would create two files, Card.js and CardList.js I would then export the components from within them individually: export default Card and export default CardList. Then I would import them individually where needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep exporting your components as default, and in your index.js you can export them like:

```
export Card from './Card/Card';
export CardList from './CardList/CardList';
```

then when using these, you can do:

```
import {Card, CardList} from 'components';
```

Your point of contact (index.js) Feels less verbose

Comment: should be `./components`. Another than this, I agree this is the best way to write *index.js* file.

Comment: `export Card from` only works in Babel and does exactly what the snippet in the question does, so it doesn't seem like this answer's the question.

Comment: Yeah, the asker never said the snippet in question didn't work, he's basically asking if there's a better way to write it, I found this to be a little a little cleaner, and its basically a popular way to do it.